# Konvajs hit boxing on shapes

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, shapes, konvajs

Im making an android app with Konvas Shape and ionic/cordova framework and I just wondering if there is any way to know the exactly position when 2 shapes hit together in one point. Something like the example of the image.

Thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKMD0.png

Comment: I'm not familiar with Konvas Shape but from the little information you offer it sounds like a collision broadphase sweep problem. Look into BulletPhysics / Blender or any other collision simulation tool or plugin.

Answer (score 0):

`Konva` has no methods to calculate it.
You have to use manual mathematics (or some math engine) to get these points.